# Obtener color en una imagen y pintarlo

Tags: python, python-3.x

Quiero conocer si aparece X color en una imagen. En este caso el color de estudio será el verde, por lo tanto su valor RGB es (0,255,0) y aplico el siguiente código:

```
    img = cv2.imread('img.jpg')

    L1 = [0, 255, 0]

    matches = np.all(img == L1, axis=2)
    result = np.zeros_like(img)

    print(result.any())
    result[matches] = [255, 0, 255]

    cv2.imwrite('resultado.jpg', result)
```

Básicamente

1. Cargo la imagen que quiero analizar.
2. Describo el valor RGB que quiero obtener.
3. Compruebo si este color (verde) aparece en la imagen.
4. Creo una imagen del tamaño de la mía completamente negra y la llamo "result".
5. Muestro por pantalla si aparece ese color mediante booleano.
6. **PINTO LA ZONA VERDE DE ROJO EN RESULT.**
7. Finalmente guardo este último paso.

A continuación muestro la imagen de estudio y posteriormente lo que se me pinta de rojo.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

¿Porque no se me pinta un recuadro igual al verde pero en rojo? ¿Porque solo eso puntitos?

¡Salud y gracias!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Igual la zona verde de tu imagen de entrada no es tan verde como crees.

Comparar con el valor `[0, 255, 0]`, sólo te producirá `[True, True, True]` si el pixel tiene *exactamente* ese valor. Si está muy cerca, por ejemplo `[1, 254, 1]` te dará `[False, False, False]`, o el caso `[1, 255, 0]` (con el que en realidad está relleno la mayor parte de tu región verde) te daría `[False, True, True]`, pero luego con el `np.all()` se reduce a `False`.

Un enfoque más flexible sería verificar que el pixel está *muy cerca* del color dado. Un método sencillo es restar al pixel el valor `[0,255,0]`, quedándose con el valor absoluto de la resta, y ver si cada componente de esa resta es menor que 3, por ejemplo (admitiríamos que la resta fuese 0, es decir color exacto, o 1, o 2, es decir "muy cerca").

Este enfoque se implementaría así:

```
matches = np.all(abs(img-L1)<3, axis=2)
```

Y el resultado sale ahora:

[image: Resultado]

Fíjate que aún hay pixeles no seleccionados cerca de la frontera del cuadrado. Estos pixeles son "menos verdes" de lo que parecían, seguramente debido a artefactos de la compresión JPG que, al estar cerca de un borde, los "mezcla" un poco con los pixeles vecinos a ese borde, por así decir.

Puedes cambiar el umbral. Por ejemplo, si en vez de 3 ponemos 5:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Gracias, no se me había ocurrido que eso pasase porque ese cuadrado lo he puesto yo manualmente (obvio) con photoshop y definiendo yo el RGB, es una faena que suceda esto porque quiero buscar longitudes de onda en imágenes y había visto que se pueden traducir a RGB, pero necesito bastante exactitud, así que se me ha ido al traste :(

Comment: No lo guardes como JPEG, que introduce "artefactos" para aumentar el ratio de compresión. Usa PNG que aunque ocupe más, respeta tu edición. En cualquier caso parece que el relleno del cuadrado no era verde puro (0,255,0), sino casi (1,255,0). Esto no lo veo ya como un artefacto JPEG, sino como un error tuyo al seleccionar el color en la paleta.

Comment: Buscar longitudes de onda en una imagen con tanta exactitud como pretendes, me parece tarea futil. La lente de la cámara o el sensor de la misma o la compresión JPG o cualquier otra cosa puede alterar perfectamente un nivel de una componente un par de unidades arriba o abajo sin que el ojo lo detecte. Pero si tu algoritmo necesita tanta precisión... también necesitarías un sensor muy preciso.

Comment: Estoy tratando de encontrar unas "manchas" en el agua y la única info que tengo de ellas es su longitud de onda, por eso mismo implementé este método. Si no, no sé cómo abordar su detección.

Comment: Pues el enfoque me parece correcto, pero el buscar un color "exacto" me parece abocado al fracaso. Cualquier factor medioambiental puede cambiarte ligeramente el color. Niebla, reflejos, hora del día...